# Bolt CMS Simple Form extension, change the reply to field to the user's email?

Tags: bolt-cms

The client is using Simple Form on her Bolt CMS website. When she receives an email from her website and she clicks 'reply', the email in the 'To' field is hers and NOT the person who submitted the enquiry form. How can this be changed? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: As far as I can see the suggestion that I was giving does not seem to work. Anyone?**

*Below, my original answer:*

In the config file for simpleforms, you can set the field with the e-mail address of the person that sent the form as the from_email, so any replies to the mail by your client will go straight to the sender.
You may also want to add a 'use_with' to add the name of the sender to the email address, in this example referring to the field "yourname", presuming that that exists.

`email:
  type: email
  use_as: from_email
  use_with: yourname`

You can find this info in the ReadMe on
https://github.com/jadwigo/SimpleForms

Comment: Thanks Evert. Ive just checked the code, and it is:

 email:
      type: email
      class: wide
      label: Email address
      required: true
      use_as: from_email
      use_with: name

It wont take the form's email input field as the from_email. It only uses the recipient_email variable. I can hardcode a from_email which works, but I dont want it hardcoded, I need it to be whatever the user has entered into the email field. I must be missing something obvious here! :/
Thanks

Comment: I had a hard time reading the non-indented code, but it seems alright. 
Just guessing: is the from_email still being overwritten at an other location in the config?

Comment: John, you were right: I happened to be working on a form somewhere else, and while I was at it I tried to implement the above solution, but to no avail. Hope somebody else will clear this up, or that a brainwave will occur on my site.

Comment: You have to disable `testmode` for this to work. Also see my answer below.